# Nature of this Multivariable Set

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $A$ is the subset of all points $(x,y)$ in the plane which satisfy either $x^{2}+y^{2}<1$ or $y=0$ . Then what is the nature of this set (i.e. open,closed,bounded,unbounded)

**Definitions** :

1. Open Set : A set (region) is said to be open if it consists of its interior points only.
2. Closed Set : A set (region) is said to be closed if it contains all of its interior and boundary points.
3. Bounded Set : A set (region) is said to be bounded if it lies inside a disk of fixed radius.
4. Unbounded Set : A set (region) is said to be unbounded if it can not lie inside a disk of fixed radius.

**My Claim** :  When a set contains some (not all) points from its boundary, then it is neither open nor closed. Moreover, it is unbounded because eventhough the disk $x^{2}+y^{2}<1$ can be fitted inside a circle on the $xy-$plane, the line $y=0$ can not.

Comment: "not closed and thus it is open" -- You might want to note that sets can be both closed and open ("clopen"), and sets can also be neither closed nor open. Just food for thought. Anyhow, it might be worth elaborating on what definitions of open, closed, bounded, and unbounded you're using, since there are several definitions a variety of people are used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A = \{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 < 1 \text{ or } y=0 \} $. Let $B_r(x_0,y_0)= \{ (x,y): (x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2<r^2\}$. To show that $A$ is not open, we just need to find $(x_0,y_0)\in A$ such that $(x_0,y_0)$ is not an interior point of $A$, any point on the line $y=0$ with $|x|>1$ would work, but in particular consider the point $(2,0)\in A$, for any $r>0$ $(2,\frac{r}{2})\in B_r(2,0)$ but $(2,\frac{r}{2})\not \in A$, thus $B_r(2,0)\not\subset A$ so $(2,0)$ is not an interior point of $A$, so we can conclude a is *not open*. To show that $A$ is not closed, it suffices to find a boundary point of $A$ which is not an element of $A$, any point on the unit circle would work, except $(\pm1,0)$, in particular, consider the point $(0,1)$ for any $r>0$, $(0,1\pm\frac{r}{2})\in B_r(0,1)$, $(0,1-\frac{r}{2})\in A$ and $(0,1+\frac{r}{2})\not\in A$, so $(0,1)$ is a boundary point of $A$, but $(0,1)$ is not in $A$, so $A$ is *not closed*. To show that $A$ is not bounded, we need to show that for all $r>0$, $A\not\subset B_r(0,0)$, but this is fairly straight forward, as $(r+1,0)\in A$ but $(r+1,0)\not\in B_r(0,0)$, so $A$ is *unbounded*.

Comment: Thank you very very much for helping me out sir!